# Fragmentshader and Vertexshader

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have problrem with my fragment.txt and vertex.txt type:

my Fragmentshader.frag is:

```
#version 330

uniform Sampler2D TexImg;
out vec4 frag_colour;
in vec2 Pass_Texcoord;

void main () {
 vec4 color = Texture2D(TexImg ,Pass_Texcoord);
 frag_colour = vec4 (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

my Vertexshader.frag is:

```
#version 330

in vec3 Pos;
in vec3 Texcoord;
out vec2 Poss_Texcoord;

void main () 
{

    gl_Position = vec4(Pos,1.0);
    Poss_Texcoord = vec2(Texcoord,1.0);

}
```

which parts is not correct?Help me please!

Comment: Download some tools for compile opengl es shaders on PC and check ... For example PowerVR tools ... pragma version doesnt looks good for me, im pretty sure that 330 for opengl ES is bad

Comment: Next `out, in` keywords ... Shouldnt be `varying, attribute`? Read the doc for opengl ES 2.0

Comment: The whole thing is incorrect, sadly. From your use of `in` and `out` instead of `attribute` and `varying` to your `#version` directive (this is a desktop GL version - try `#version 100` instead) and even your texture function is wrong, use: `texture2D (...)`. GLSL is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

I have corrected your shaders for you and commented everything that was wrong with them.

#### Fragment Shader:

```
#version 100                     // OpenGL ES 2.0 uses different version numbers

uniform Sampler2D TexImg;

varying vec2      Pass_Texcoord; // Use varying instead of in for FS inputs
//out vec4        frag_colour;   // Invalid in OpenGL ES 2.0

void main ()
{
  // Interestingly, you do not use this value anywhere so GLSL will treat this as
  //   a no-op and remove this when it comes time to compile this shader.
  vec4 color = texture2D (TexImg, Pass_Texcoord); // Also, use texture2D

  // You must write to gl_FragData [n] or gl_FragColor in OpenGL ES 2.0
  gl_FragColor = vec4 (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

#### Vertex Shader:

```
#version 100                     // OpenGL ES 2.0 uses different version numbers

attribute vec3 Pos;              // Use attribute instead of in for vtx. attribs
attribute vec3 Texcoord;         // Use attribute instead of in for vtx. attribs

varying   vec2 Poss_Texcoord;    // Use varying instead of out for VS outputs

void main () 
{
  gl_Position   = vec4 (Pos,      1.0);

  /* Constructing a vec2 from 4 components is invalid
  Poss_Texcoord = vec2 (TexCoord, 1.0); */
  Poss_Texcoord = Texcoord.st;   // Use this instead
}
```